# iPhone - Localizable.strings - string with single quotes inside

Tags: ios, iphone, nslocalizedstring

I need to add some french translation into iOS Application. But I don know how to use single qute char in the Localizable.strings file.
For example text :

```
"Invalid username or password."="Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect.";
```

Causes an error. I've tried adding backslashes, but it havn't worked as well.

Comment: Strange, for me this string doesn't produce an error
"Invalid username or password."="Nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect.";

Comment: It was my fault, I have been using slashes instead of backslashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try escaping it with a backslash?

```
"\'"
```

As a last resort you could use [direct U codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html):

> You can include arbitrary Unicode characters in a value string by
>   specifying \U followed immediately by up to four hexadecimal digits.
>   The four digits denote the entry for the desired Unicode character;
>   for example, the space character is represented by hexadecimal 20 and
>   thus would be \U0020 when specified as a Unicode character. This
>   option is useful if a string must include Unicode characters that for
>   some reason cannot be typed. If you use this option, you must also
>   pass the -u option to genstrings in order for the hexadecimal digits
>   to be interpreted correctly in the resulting strings file. The
>   genstrings tool assumes your strings are low-ASCII by default and only
>   interprets backslash sequences if the -u option is specified.

The apostrophe should be \U0027

Answer (score 2):

> Using Special Characters in String Resources Just as in C, some
>   characters must be prefixed with a backslash before you can include
>   them in the string. These characters include double quotation marks,
>   the backslash character itself, and special control characters such as
>   linefeed (\n) and carriage returns (\r).

From:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html